# collection.save() does not work in mongodb correctly

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema

.save() doesn't do anything can you help me out with that? Here, are my code snippets

**Mongoose connection**

```yaml
const dbOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

const connection = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.DB_URL, dbOptions, () => { console.log('connected to db') })

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: connection, collection: 'sessions' })

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 300
  }
}))
```

**User Schema**

```yaml
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  hash: {
    type: String
  },
  salt: {
    type: String
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)
```

**Routing**
Herein code executes till creating hash and salt I tried using the console statements, but does nothing further.

```yaml
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

const User = require('../models/User')
const passport = require('passport')
const genPassword = require('../passwordUtil').genPassword

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const findusers = await User.find()
    res.json(findusers)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err })
  }
})

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const salthash = genPassword(req.body.password)

  const hash = salthash.hash
  const salt = salthash.salt

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    hash: hash,
    salt: salt
  })

  try {
    const saveduser = user.save()
    res.json(saveduser)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err })
  }
})

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, next) => {})

module.exports = router
```

Also, Idk if this is required but here's my app.js file please let me know if you find anything wrong. In my opinion this one's healthy but just to be sure. Please review this and let me know.
**App.js**

```yaml
var createError = require('http-errors')
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var logger = require('morgan')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv/config')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
require('./authenticate')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users')

var app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyparser.json())

const dbOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

const connection = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.DB_URL, dbOptions, () => { console.log('connected to db') })

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: connection, collection: 'sessions' })

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 300
  }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404))
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

  res.status(err.status || 500)
  res.render('error')
})

module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny mistake in your code.

I mean this part of your code:

```js
try {
    const saveduser = user.save()
    res.json(saveduser)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err })
  }
```

As you know interacting with databases is node asynchronously. So if you want to put your saved user in a `savedUser` variable you have to use `await`. If you do not use `await` you will get `undefined` in response.

Here is the correct code:

```js
await user.save()
```

**UPDATE**

The whole code will be like this (Using async/await):

```js
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const salthash = genPassword(req.body.password)

  const hash = salthash.hash
  const salt = salthash.salt

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    hash: hash,
    salt: salt
  })

  try {
    await user.save();
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err })
  }
})
```

And using Promise:

```js
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const salthash = genPassword(req.body.password)

  const hash = salthash.hash
  const salt = salthash.salt

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    hash: hash,
    salt: salt
  })

  user.save().then(() => {
    const savedUser = user;
    res.json(saveduser);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json({ message: err })
  })
})
```

Comment: But await works only with async functions. I don't think this is a resolution to the problem.

Comment: You can make your function async, or use Promise or callback.

Comment: And another thing I consider is that Model.save() does not return saved object but it updates the existing object. I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. There's no error tho but it's not saving my data into db